# Gnuplot: how to only draw xtics without tic lables on top

Tags: plot, border, gnuplot

I want to draw xtics on top but without its tic labels:

This is what I want:

[image]

This is the code I tried:

```
set xtics mirror;
set border 2+4;
plot x;
```

This gave me:

[image]

How can I modify the script to get what I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove the tick labels with `set format x ''`, but that still leaves the xtics at the bottom.

In my opinion, the best way is to use only the x2-axis

```
set ytics nomirror
unset xtics
set x2tics nomirror
set format x2 ''
set border 2+4
plot x axes x2y1
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can make the color of the font as the background color e.g. for white background

```
set xtics out offset -1.,0 scale 2.2  enhanced font 'Helvetica:bold,45' tc  rgb  "#FFFFFF"
```